# Entity Framework join 3 tables query error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Error:

> Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. Did you intend to
>   invoke the
>   method?   D:\PROJECTS\CECB2013-03-26\CECB\cecb.Functions\ActivationCodeEmail.cs   102 20  cecb.Functions*

My code is

```
 List<Members> teamMembers = new List<Members>();

 var query = from c in cecbContext.Projects
             join b in cecbContext.TeamMembers on c.proj_team equals b.team_reference
             join d in cecbContext.Members on b.mem_reference equals d.mem_reference
             select new
                    {
                        d.mem_reference
                    };

    return query.ToList<Members>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten the brackets after `ToList` - it's an ( extension ) method:

```
return query.ToList<Members>();
```

You have another problem, though - you trying to turn an `IQueryable<AnonymousType>` into a `List<Members>`.

If you create instances of `Members` in your `Select` clause, it will work and you will be able to omit the generic type parameter on `ToList()`

```
select new Members
{
  ...
};

return query.ToList(); // this will create a List<Members>
```

Comment: no buddy then it say's


Error 6 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Gayashan oh - you have to add `using System.Linq;` too as `IQueryable<T>.ToList()` is an extension method.

Comment: Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<cecbData.Members>' 

again im getting this error

Comment: @Gayashan That's because you're selecting an anonymous type with `select new { ... }`. See the second part of my answer. You could start a new question as this is a different problem.